# Elmah does not send emails on errors running on windows azure websites

Tags: azure, elmah, azure-web-app-service

When I publish my site to windows azure, ELMAH does not send emails and throws the error below.
Any help or ideas appreciated. Thank You!

**Note:**

I have elmah setup properly to send emails via smtp on hostmysite.com which does IIS/.NET hosting outside of Azure.
I also have a staging server at home that works well.
Also, I have tried port 25,50, 587.
Also, I have tried sending to a list server I pay for and also SendGrid.
In each case, it works on my staging and development server but not in Azure.

ELMAH is capturing errors in the database (MS SQL and IIS in Azure).

Here are my config settings:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationExceptionAccess is denied

System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.GetFixedInfo()
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.get_FixedInfo()
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.get_HostName()
   **at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Initialize()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient..ctor()
   at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.SendMail(MailMessage mail)
   at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.ReportError(Error error)**
   at Elmah.ErrorSignalEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ErrorSignalEventArgs args)
   at Elmah.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext     controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at     System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


        <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
...
    </httpModules>
      <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
...
    </modules>


<elmah>
     <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql" />
    **<errorMail from="errors@domain.com" to="ErrorReport@mydomain.com" subject="[Site][ErrorReport-ELMAH]" async="false" smtpPort="587" smtpServer="stmp.server.com" useSsl="false" userName="user1" password="password1" noYsod="false" />**
  </elmah>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue (test/dev working, production "access denied") our staging environment used to work, but we've just moved to a new azure host for prod and staging and it's "access denied" for those since. I've filled an issue with the Sendgrid guys, waiting for the outcome.

Comment: jmettraux, It is most likely not sendgrid.

Comment: jmettraux,  It is most likely not sendgrid.  I can get sendgrid to send emails on the same site that elmah is on.  Also, I tried with a smtp account at another host called hostmysite.com.  There is a list server there I can access and Elmah will not send to that either from Azure.  Elmah sends from my staging with either sendgrid or hostmysite.com.  We need some Azure engineers to pitch in.

Comment: Well, then I'm going to fill a request to the Azure support.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and got help from Microsoft Support. Apparently, switching from 64 bits to 32 bits in the Azure dashboard fixes it. 64 bits and it's "access denied", 32 bits and the emails go through.

OK, apparently the Azure team rolled a fix for this 64 bits issue. 64 bits and 32 bits work for me. They say they deployed the fix yesterday (2013/06/20).

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of ELMAH (v1.2 SP2) can only send email through SMTP, which is not natively supported in Azure.  (Probably because it would turn into a huge SPAM engine).

Since ELMAH is included in the project as an HTTP Module I actually had to download & modify the [source](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.2-sp2-src.zip) to handle Exchange Online Web Services to get email working in our Azure Cloud Service.  The code is very clean so you should only have to modify ErrorMailModule.cs. I added in the appropriate web.config input parameters and then created a new Send method inserting it like so (preserving backwards compatibility):

```
ReportError(Error error)
{
  ...

 OnMailing(args);
 if (UseExchangeWebServices)  //pulled from web.config
 {
     SendExchangeMail(mail);
 }
 else
 {
     SendMail(mail);
 }

....
}

//Sample web.config
<elmah>
<errorMail to="WebMaster@sample.com"
           subject="Sample - Elmah Exception"
           async="true"
           exchangeUserName="Admin@sample.onmicrosoft.com"
           exchangePassword="supersecretpassword"
           autoDiscoverUrl="Admin@sample.onmicrosoft.com"
           useExchangeWebServices="true"/>
</elmah>
```

Then I just uploaded the code to our corporate Nuget server for easy consumption.  I've used SendGrid's API before, you should be able to do something similar.

Edit:
Went ahead and added the NuGet Package here:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah.ews/